# Django's password_reset keeps returning error

Tags: django, passwords

I'm trying to use Django's built in password_reset view, and so far I followed a small tutorial, but in my case, and as I found out, also many other people's, it doesn't work, and everytime I access the specific url, it returns: "Reverse for 'reset_password' not found. 'reset_password' is not a valid view function or pattern name.". I looked for all kinds of solutions, but the only one that actually worked was to move the urls with password_reset and password_reset_confirm to the main urls.py, instead of the one in my subdirectory. Still, if I access the url "raw", aka just typing it instead of rendering the page through link and all, it does indeed work, but If I try to access it through some actual link, it returns the very same error I got from the start.

In my main/urls.py :

```
url(r'^reset_password/$', password_reset, name='password_reset'),
url(r'^reset_password/done/$', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
```

^This one doesn't work in any way, it just returns that error. I checked for possible typos or bad declaration, but it is alright.

Like I said, if I take these two urls and put them in urls.py instead of main/urls.py, it does work. But then I tried to implement a link in a template, like this: `{% url 'reset_password' %}`. But it returns that error instead.

Comment: I'll try to be more specific then. Originally, I wanted to use those two urls not in the main app urls.py, but in urls.py in my subdirectory, called main. The problem is, it wouldn't work and it would always print that error message. Using them in main/urls.py was indeed my first attempt. Then I found out that if I put those two urls in my main app urls.py, it does work. My main issue is that I can't use them in main/urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your urls here is `password_reset` and `password_reset_done`.

So you would call them like this in the template -

`{% url 'password_reset' %}`

`{% url 'password_reset_done' %}`

Notice that the name you have defined in urls.py is different from the name you are using in the template. It is because of this that `reverse` is unable to find the correct url.